# Auto Click all Links In Div ID

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, onclick

I have a WP blog page which shows recent posts using category shortcodes
On that page, i have a list of links leading to their posts. 
I can't edit the links to add id or class to them, so i am manually using a div to wrap the shortcode and a javascript which makes the links open to new tab upon click, is there a way i can open all the links to new tabs open single click? (REMEMBER, I CANT EDIT THE LINKS)
Here is my codes

```
<!--- i cant edit the links below ----->

<div id="boss" class="boss">
<a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 2</a>
 <a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 3</a>
<a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 4</a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('boss').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        a[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
  }
</script>
```

am trying to load all the links to their new tabs upon click

```
<div onclick="boss();">Something To Click On</div>
```

ITS NOT WORKING, ANY HELP PLS?

Comment: Whats the boss function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Fullcode example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function boss() {

            var a = document.getElementById('boss').getElementsByTagName('a');

            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                openNewTab(a[i], "click");

            }
        }

        function openNewTab(obj, evtName) {

            try {
                if (obj.dispatchEvent !== null && obj.dispatchEvent !== undefined) {
                    //var event = new Event(evtName);
                    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    event.initMouseEvent(evtName, true, true, window,
                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    obj.dispatchEvent(event);
                } else if (obj.fireEvent !== null && obj.fireEvent !== undefined) {
                    event = document.createEventObject();
                    event.button = 1;
                    obj.fireEvent("on" + evtName, event);
                    obj.fireEvent(evtName);
                } else {
                    obj[evtName]();
                }
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div onclick="boss();">Something To Click On</div>
        <div id="boss">
            <a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 1</a>
            <a href="http://example.com/example-2" title="Example 1">Example 2</a>
            <a href="http://example.com/example-3" title="Example 1">Example 3</a>
            <a href="http://example.com/example-4" title="Example 1">Example 4</a>
        </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: the function openNewTab() not working?.you received some error in try->catch?

Comment: The div isn't clickable and noting happens when being hover on... Can you show me a working example of this pls?

Answer (score 0):

That would be easy with jQuery. You can use `.each()` and `.attr()` to achieve it.

**NOTE**
Try this script in your WordPress. Since the below output is a iframe, it won't work!

```js
$ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#boss > a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("target","_blank");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boss" class="boss">
<a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 2</a>
 <a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 3</a>
<a href="http://example.com/example-1" title="Example 1">Example 4</a>
</div>
```

Good Luck :)